# Only get records with a full match

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having two tables and I need to get all records with a full match. Meaning joining Table A on Table B where all records in B have a specific value.

#### My tables:

**Product Table**

```
id | name
------------------
 1 | Product one
 2 | Product two
 3 | Product three
```

**Media Table**

```
id | product_id | feed
----------------------
 1 |          1 |    1
 2 |          1 |    1
 3 |          1 |    3
 4 |          2 |    3
 5 |          2 |    3
 6 |          3 |    1
 7 |          3 |    1
 8 |          3 |    1
 9 |          3 |    1
```

#### The result I am looking for

I want all records from table `product` where all referring records in table `media` have a `feed` value `3`

```
p.id | p.name      | m.feed
---------------------------
   2 | Product two |      3
```

I tried a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but that also returns me `Product one` and `Product two`. [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1eff53/2)

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, m.feed
FROM product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN media m ON p.id = m.product_id
WHERE m.feed = 3

UNION
SELECT p.id, p.name, m.feed
FROM product p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN media m ON p.id = m.product_id
WHERE m.feed = 3
```

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: why not product 1?  media.id 3 has product.id of 1 and feed of 3

Comment: @LoztInSpace, I only need the products where all feed values are 3, not just one, but ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.id, p.name, 3 as feed
    FROM product p
    INNER JOIN media m ON p.id = m.product_id
    GROUP BY p.id, p.name 
HAVING max(m.feed)=3 and min(m.feed)=3
```

Comment: This is exactly matches my question and will mark is as the answer. But StephaneM answer gave me another insight that I'm going to use!

Answer (score 1):

This one will work:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from media m
                where m.product_id=p.id and m.feed <>3)
```

Note that I removed the m.feed from the select because you know its value will be 3.

Comment: Note that this query returns also products for which there is no media row.

Comment: good catch @Renzo THat helped me with my (hopefully correct) answer